# any way to not use suspend in vue 3 for composition api async?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a composition API to fetch data by Async in `setup()` but I should define like this in another component

```html
    <Suspense>
      <template #default>
        <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js + TypeScript App" />
      </template>
      <template #fallback>
        <div>Loading...</div>
      </template>
    </Suspense>
```

if I don't use `<Suspense>`, that component not rendering in my app, how can i solve this?

Comment: You can't avoid the `<Suspense>` component if you're using `async setup()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using `v-if` and `v-else`. You should also make the data reactive in case you haven't already done that.

```
<template>
<div v-if="data">
    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js + TypeScript App" />
</div>
<div v-else>
    Loading...
</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, reactive } from 'vue';
export default defineComponent({
    setup() {
        const data = reactive({});

        return {
            data,
        };
    },
});
</script>
```